# SQL Error when I use a single quote in a description box

Tags: php, sql, odbc, parameterized

I have built a website to submit timesheets for my small business. It uses SQL statements to submit data to a Microsoft Access database via ODBC. I've now noticed whenever I use a single quote in my description box, it gives me an error.

I read up on this and am hearing lots of people say 'parameterize your queries', but I'm unsure on how to do that.

I have an HTML textbox on my website as such

```
<textarea name="JobDescription" cols="75" rows="8" id="otherpurch"></textarea><br>
```

It's part of a form and is submitted along with various other things. How would I deal with the inclusion of single quotes in the description typed in this box? I have a .php file titled 'submit_form' where I'd imagine that would have to be done. What is the general procedure for parameterizing your queries? I'm a little confused on that.

Any help is immensely appreciated!

Here is how the data is sent from the textbox to the database.

```
$JobDescription=$_POST['JobDescription'];
$JobDescription=stripslashes($JobDescription);
$JobDescription=mysql_real_escape_string($JobDescription);

//make connection to database, bail if no connection
$connection = odbc_pconnect('db','','');
if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

//Send data (usually there are many other variables being sent, but I removed them
//for the purposes of showing you just the text being sent from the description box

$sql = "INSERT INTO TimeSheet ('$JobDescription')";
$rs = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
if (!$rs) { exit("Error in SQL");
```

Comment: The problem is not in the HTML, but in the PHP code saving the data back to the database. Post that.

Comment: You cannot call `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you do not have an open `mysql_connect()` resource.  In other words, it is not a generic function to use with any db API, and it may return an empty string...

Comment: And the good news is that you learned about SQL Injection the easy way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intention to use parametrized SQL is correct, and Access via ODBC supports that as well.

For the functions to use instead of `odbc_exec`, see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php

```
$JobDescription=$_POST['JobDescription']; // no escaping needed!

$connection = odbc_pconnect('db','','');
if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

$stmt = odbc_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO TimeSheet (?)");
$rs = odbc_execute($stmt, array($JobDescription));
```